# .htaccess add trailing slash if no extension before the last trailing slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a code here which rewrites url by adding trailing slash at the end.
Condition:

1. No File Extension
2. No slash at the end

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/Brian/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

If the url is:

```
http://localhost:8080/Brian/test123 -> http://localhost:8080/Brian/test123/ - CORRECT
http://localhost:8080/Brian/test123. -> http://localhost:8080/Brian/test123. - CORRECT
http://localhost:8080/Brian/test123.awd -> http://localhost:8080/Brian/test123.awd - CORRECT

http://localhost:8080/Brian/test123.awd/a -> http://localhost:8080/Brian/test123.awd/a - THIS IS MY PROBLEM
```

I want to make the result like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/Brian/test123.awd/a/
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..*$
> ```

So it would seem you need to only look in the *last* path segment, rather than *anywhere* in the URL-path. (Incidentally, the above *CondPattern* is the same as `!\.`)

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^/]*$
```

`[^/]*` matches any character except slash to the end of the string, so it will only match last path segments that are not followed by a slash.

---

*Aside:* It looks like your `.htaccess` file is located inside the `/Brian` subdirectory. You could "simplify" this a bit and avoid having to explicitly state the subdirectory in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^/]*$
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `!/$` simply checks that the requested URL-path does not already end in a slash (instead of capturing everything when a slash does not occur at the end). The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full (root-relative, starting with a slash) URL-path, which we have already ascertained does not end in a slash.

Providing you are redirecting to the same scheme + hostname, you don't necessarily need to include this in the *substitution* string.

Comment: Yes indeed that is the problem ++